Find the pixel sensitivity of a Convolutional Neural Network
So assume I have a simple convolutional neural network with 2 or 3 convolutional layers, a pooling layer, and whatever else is typical. The network takes in an image and tries to produce an image that matches the output image. Basically the network is being trained to fit to a transformation.
When we train a CNN, we find the gradients for the weights.
For my work, I'm looking for the gradients of the pixels instead. So basically, the sensitivity of the output pixels of the CNN to the input pixels.
Would this be possible to get? I know the gradients of a convolutional layer are relatively straightforward. But is there a simple way to extract the sensitivity for the overall network
